# How do I filter results using the SxaTags field while in the Content Editor search UI?

Tags: sxa, buckets, search-facet

Sitecore 8.2.7 + SXA 1.7.0

I've created a new Facet entry like the following:

[image: Bucket Facet]

Then I'm testing the search on a folder marked as an item bucket:

[image: Bucketed Search]

The facet never appears:

[image: Facet List]

What should I try next?

### Update

After applying the Global setting it started to work as I expect.

[image: Working Search]

Comment: Related article that might be useful : https://sitecore.namics.com/2017/11/13/customized-sitecore-search-view-list-buckets-values-in-dynamic-placeholders/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **global** and **local** facet types, if you want the SXATags to be global, there is checkbox Global on the facet item to check, if for specific items (local), you will need to update the facets field on the targeted item, here is the link for Sitecore documentation:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/facets.html

Here is a screenshot for facets field:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing.